# Kentico 8: For what use is the CMSApp_AppCode Project?

Tags: kentico

Can anywhone explain what the CMSApp_AppCode Project in Kentico 8 is for? 
What are its benefits and what do I put into that project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote to the Kentico Support and they stated:

> The purpose of CMSApp_AppCode solution is especially about the
>   over-rided classes and other customizations that are **over-riding
>   default behavior of application.**

So if you customize the default behavior it is now easier to apply updates and hotfixes, because the customizations are now in a seperate project.